# SQLAlchemy Marshmallow returns empty JSON Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow, flask-marshmallow

I am trying to return all user info, but every time I run the request it returns an empty JSON object

My model and schema:

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

db = SQLAlchemy()
ma = Marshmallow()


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, name, email, password):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.password = password


class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    class meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'email', 'password')


user_schema = UserSchema()
```

The GET function:

```py
@auth.route('/getuser/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_user(id):
    password = request.json['password']

    user = User.query.get(id)

    if not user or not bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf-8'), user.password.encode('utf-8')):
        return jsonify({'msg': 'Wrong email or password'})

    result = user_schema.dump(user)

    return result
```

When the user is added to the database the password is converted to a plain string

Comment: Do you need to specify that `id` is an `int` in the route?  `@auth.route('/getuser/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])`

Comment: I'd add a print(result) to see what happens.

Comment: Don't you need to jsonify(result)?

Comment: I had a print and it also returned empty, and changing the id to int didn't help. Jsonify makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

In order to return all the details of a specific user, you can use the following code :

```
def get_user(id):
    user = User.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    if user is not None:
        response = jsonify({'result':user.to_json()})
    else
        response = jsonify({'message': 'cannot find user'}), 404
    return response
```

The code shared has the details of obtaining the user details in JSON format.

Comment: user.to_json() return error. AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'to_json'

Comment: Have you tried importing pandas library in the project. to_json() is panda library function.